# Javascript throwing TypeError, document.getElementById when passed PHP variable

Tags: php, javascript, html, variables

I'm trying to write a function that will dynamically display a form (inside a div, of which there will be several instances, thus the weird "id" name) when you click a button. Then, it should POST to a separate PHP file. Here's the code I have so far:

```
function add_comment_url($table, $id) {
    $html = '<div id="comment' . $id . '" name="comment_box" style="display: none">
        <form action="cgi-bin/add_comment.php" method="post">
            <textarea id="comment" name="comment"></textarea>
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $id . '">
            <input type="hidden" name="table" value="' . $table . '">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Comment">
        </form></div>
        <input type="button" value="Add Comment" onclick="showComment();">
        <script>
    var id= ' . json_encode($id) . ';
    showComment(id);
    </script>';

    return($html);
}
```

The "Add Comment" button shows up fine, but I can't get the  to display, and the Firefox console shows a "TypeError: div is null" error when I click on the button.

I'm guessing I screwed up the JS variable assignment, but I'm at a loss as to how to fix it. Any thoughts?

EDIT - Final code

I figured out what I did wrong... I was defining the `var` when I didn't need to! Here's the new function, which works:

```
function add_comment_url($table, $id) {
$html = '<div id="comment' . $id . '" name="comment_box" style="display: none">
    <form action="cgi-bin/add_comment.php" method="post">
        <textarea id="comment" name="comment"></textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $id . '">
        <input type="hidden" name="table" value="' . $table . '">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Comment">
    </form></div>
    <input type="button" value="Add Comment" onclick="showComment(' . $id . ');">';

return($html);
```

}

Comment: If you had looked at the page source your browser receives, you would have noticed that `var id= "<?php echo json_encode($id); ?>";` does not produce the expected output.

Comment: I did notice that, which is why I knew it was a variable issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `<?php` inside PHP strings. You should use string concatenation or interpolation:

```
function add_comment_url($table, $id) {
    $html = '<div id="comment' . $id . '" name="comment_box" style="display: none">
        <form action="cgi-bin/add_comment.php" method="post">
            <textarea id="comment" name="comment"></textarea>
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $id . '">
            <input type="hidden" name="table" value="' . $table . '">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Comment">
        </form></div>
        <input type="button" value="Add Comment" onclick="showComment();">
        <script>
        function showComment() {
        var id= ' . json_encode($id) . ';
        div = document.getElementById(\'comment\' + id);
        div.style.display = "block";}</script>';
    return($html);
}
```

Are you repeating this function definition for every comment block? I would recommend just defining `showComment()` once, and make it take the `commentID` as an argument.

Comment: You don't need the double quotes in the JS code surrounding `json_encode`.

Comment: @DCoder Good point. And if `$id` is always a number, you don't really need `json_encode`.

Comment: @Barmar - Thanks, that cleared up the JS error! However, the <div> doesn't appear when the button is clicked....

Comment: Are there multiple copies of this code on the page? If so, the `showComment` function will only be the last one defined. You really should do what I suggested: define the function once, and pass the ID in the argument.

Comment: @Barmar - Yes, but I changed it as per what you said about taking the `commentId` as a variable. Still no dice. To be more clear, the function is now only declared once, and the `var id = ' . json_encode($id) . ';` is all that I have in the comment blocks now.

Comment: Please add your new code to the question so I can see what you're doing.

Comment: There shouldn't be any `var id` in the comment blocks now.

Comment: Show the new version of `add_comment_url()`, so I can see how you're passing the ID.